# How to write a .dat file for MPlus statistical software format?

Tags: r

Simple question, I've tried looking for this online and in forums and found:

`write.dat(df, filename)` but It seems I don't have the package to do so. Anyone know which packages allow writing a `.dat` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please load below library for `write.dat()`

```
library(multiplex)
```

Or

```
library(foreign)
```